# Fixed position on scroll flickering

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, fixed

I have a simple page with a `header` and a `nav`. On window scroll I set the `header` and `nav` to a `fixed` position. All goes well if the page is long enough to scroll. If the page is at a certain height I get a flickering situation.

```js
var prev = 0;
var $window = $(window);
var nav = $('.context-nav');
var $navbar = $('.navbar');

$(window).scroll(function(e) {
  var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
  nav.toggleClass('fixed', scrollTop >= prev);
  $navbar.toggleClass('fixed', scrollTop >= prev);
  prev = scrollTop;
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

html,
body {
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #8ca986, #789a71);
}

.sp {
  height: 700px;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04), 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) 0s;
}

header.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 60px;
}

.page-container {
  padding: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

.page-container .context-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.page-container .context-nav.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
}

.page-container .context-nav .nav-item {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="navbar">
  My header goes here
</header>
<div class="page-container">
  <div class="context-nav">
    <div class="nav-item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="nav-item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="nav-item">Item 3</div>
  </div>
  <h1 class="sp">Scroll me... </h1>
</div>
```

You can see the problem if you adjust the height of the class `.sp` to a small size. In my sample I have set it to `700px`. When I try to scroll it sets the class but removes it directly which is causing the flickering behavior. When I set the `.sp` class height to `1200px` the problem is not there.

Does anyone have an idea to fix this?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/talsja/pen/BMyXPL)

Comment: In future please please all relevant code within the question. I've done it for you in this instance

Answer (score 1):

Flicker happens because when you set the element to position fixed, it goes out of the flow and that changes the offset, if what you're looking for is to display stickyElements upon scroll, I'd suggest to clone the element you want to display as sticky into a fixed container and then display that container, this way the original element stay in their original position and do not cause the content jump, also i noticed you were using a counter to display and hide the stickyElements, which i think is inefficient unless you have a different thing in your mind.

Here is a codepen i quickly forked from yours to show what i mean:

```js
var $window = $(window);
var $stickyHeader = $('.stickyHeader');
var $nav = $('.context-nav');
var navOffset = $nav.offset().top;
var $navbar = $('.navbar');
var $newNavBar = $navbar.clone();
var $newNav = $nav.clone();

$stickyHeader.append($newNavBar);
$stickyHeader.append($newNav);
var timer;

$(window).scroll(function (e) {
 if(timer) {
  window.clearTimeout(timer);
 }

 timer = window.setTimeout(function(){
  if($window.scrollTop() > navOffset) {
   $stickyHeader.addClass('active');
  }
  else { 
   $stickyHeader.removeClass('active');
  }
 }, 100);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

html,
body {
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #8ca986, #789a71);
}

.sp {
  height: 700px;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04), 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}
.active header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}

.page-container {
  padding: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

.context-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.active .context-nav {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
}
.context-nav .nav-item {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.stickyHeader {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: -140px;
  transition: height 200ms ease, top 200ms ease;
}
.stickyHeader.active {
  height: 140px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stickyHeader">
 
</div>
<header class="navbar">
 My header goes here
</header>
<div class="page-container"> 
 <div class="context-nav">
  <div class="nav-item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="nav-item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="nav-item">Item 3</div>
 </div>
 <h1 class="sp">Scroll me... </h1>
</div>
```

`https://codepen.io/j-lastforone/pen/bzddmK`

Comment: Hi San, thanks for your reply. Cloning makes it a little more complex because the navbar and especially the context-nav contains elements which have different js events attached when the user clicks on table rows.  When cloning i must reattach all these events etc which makes the code complex and more difficult to maintain. Also iwhen the page is long enough to scroll i have no problems at all. The flickering only occurred when the page height is at a certain height. You definitely helpt me to look in a different direction. Thank you for that

Comment: No problem, `$.clone()` allows you to copy events as well, in fact it allows you to even do a deep-copy, it just depends on how you use it. https://api.jquery.com/clone/

and to understand the problem try to console.log value of `prev` in the eventhandler, you'll see what i mean.

Comment: I know about copy and deep copy. That isn't an issue.
The context-nav get's activated and values get set on row click inside a grid. Also the context-nav get's rendered in a razor view from an action the first time. After that ajax will update the context-menu etc. If i clone, i have to maintain both copies etc which will cause spaggetti code